# Setting a softwarelimit to RAM in Linux

Tags: linux, memory

For testing purpose of an application, I would like to limit the RAM of a server. I prefere not to remove the RAM-sticks. I could not find an option in the BIOS. Is there a way to modify this in the Linux configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ulimit -d $SIZE_IN_KB` to limit the data segment of the current bash shell and whatever you launch from it. `help ulimit` in bash gives you the documentation.

ETA: If you want to limit the whole system, set `mem=1G` as a boot parameter in grub ([doc](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/BootPrompt-HOWTO.html#ss3.3)).

Comment: Great, it works!